# How to load interstitial after click, but before new intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, admob, interstitial

My main page has about 10 buttons and each button loads a new intent.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }

        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.troop_button:
                gotoTroopScreen();
                break;
        }
    }


public void gotoTroopScreen()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, troop.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I want the user to click the button, view the interstitial, then view the Troop screen. Right now, it loads the Troop Screen first, then shows the interstitial after the user exits the Troop Screen. Is there a way to make the interstitial show first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load your add in `onCreate`, like this

```
 interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);   
 interstitial.setAdUnitId("YOUR_AD_UNIT_IT");

 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();

 interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And then on button click, call following function:

```
 public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
 }
```

And when user close ad, move to next activity:

```
// Set an AdListener.
 mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
             @Override
             public void onAdLoaded() {
                 //Here set a flag to know that your 
             }

             @Override
             public void onAdClosed() {
                 // Proceed to the next activity.
                 goToNextActivity();
             }
         });
```

**Note:** There is a possibility that, user will click button before, `interstitial` ad has been loaded.

Comment: I've already done the first two steps. How exactly does the `goToNextActivity()` work? The user can click any of the 10 buttons and each button loads a different activity.

Comment: you have to set flag, to know which button user have clicked

Comment: And then you can use switch() in onAdClosed() callback

Comment: Thanks! The only thing I have done differently was set a global variable in `public void onClick(View v)` for the button id and then put the switch statement in `onAdClosed()`.  `onAdLoaded()` doesn't seem necessary here because the app should technically record the click immediately after press and not when the ad loads.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate method outside for Displaying the ad function and call the method inside your switch case before calling your gotoTroopScreen() method call your ad method, it should display your ad unit first.